# How to write a UDF that uses the cell it is written in as a refrence

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a UDF that returns the RGB value of the background color of the cell it is written in. How does one refrence the cell in which the UDF is written without specifying the cell?

I'd like my function to work the same way the `=COLUMN()` worksheet function does.

Supplying `ActiveCell` does not work... because the activecell will something else when a recalc is done of the sheet.

```
Function BackgroundAsRGB(Optional rng As Range)
On Error GoTo Hell
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = ActiveCell 'It isn't active cell...
    End If
    BackgroundAsRGB = ColorLongToRGB(rng.Resize(1, 1).Interior.Color)
Hell:
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
    Function BackgroundAsRGB(Optional rng As Range)
Dim MyTarget As Range

If rng Is Nothing Then
    Set MyTarget = Application.Caller
Else
   Set MyTarget = rng
End If

BackgroundAsRGB = ColorLongToRGB(MyTarget.Resize(1, 1).Interior.Color)

End Function
```

`Application.Caller` returns the object that is invoking the UDF, so it returns the range where you execute this UDF. More info:

> **[Application.Caller property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller)**

Also, check:

> **[Application.ThisCell property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thiscell)**

Comment: That is it! Thank you... haven't considered looking at the Application object... was totally focused on Range and Cells and Worksheet. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Thanks @rohrl77 . If it worked for you, please, mark it as correct so the question will be closed :)

Comment: No worries. I never leave questions open.

Comment: Checl updated code. I replaced line `ColorLongToRGB(rng.Resize(1, 1).Interior.Color)` with `ColorLongToRGB(MyTarget.Resize(1, 1).Interior.Color)` because is the right one. Sorry about that

Comment: You can also check out `Application.ThisCell`

Comment: Did not know about `ThisCell` :O Thanks @TimWilliams